# How to set light colors instead of bold in PS (shell prompt)

Tags: arch-linux, colors

I have an Archlinux installed on headless RaspberryPi. I'm using SSH to connect to it.

I've added some colors to bash with editing

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc
```

and adding:

```
PS1='[\[\e[1;34m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\[\e[1;32m\]\h\[\e[m\] \[\e[1m\]\W\[\e[m\]]\$'
```

The only problem is, that the colors like **1;34** is not displayed as **Light Blue**, but as **Bold Blue** which is hard to read on the black terminal. Is there any way to set the colors to their "light variants"?

Comment: `\e[1;34m` is bold, `\e[0;34m` is normal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this site/service to generate the colors that you want.

- [Bash $PS1 Generator](http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html)

**NOTE:** I think you're looking for the color Cyan to get light blue: (Cyan - 0;36).

*excerpt*

[image: ss of app#1]

[image: ss of app#2]

#### References

- [How to Customize Your Command Prompt](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/how-to-customize-your-command-prompt/)